# How to disable mouse scrolling in Ubuntu?

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll, edubuntu, mouse-wheel

How to disable mouse scrolling Without Terminal?
And with Terminal?

I searched in the System settings menu but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You may be referring to the touchpad. If so,

Go to `System Settings` -> `Mouse and Touchpad` -> `Touchpad tab` -> `Scrolling`,

click  <kbd>Disabled</kbd>